# Mapproxy WMTS rendering in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, wmts, mapproxy

I have been working on a mapproxy WMS/WMTS service for imagery. Everything has gone relatively smooth, except for when loading the WMTS service in ArcMap. Certain tiles are blurry and never adjust resolution when changing scale. However, the WMTS service works fine in QGIS and even ArcGIS Online.

What could I be missing in my configuration? Or is there another issue I am not aware of?

Link to the demo page: http://162.222.183.191:8080/demo/

EDIT:
WMTS GetCapabilities link: http://162.222.183.191:8080/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

```
    services:
      demo:
      tms:
        use_grid_names: true
        origin: 'nw'
      wmts:
        restful: true
        restful_template: '/{Layer}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.{Format}'
        kvp: true
        srs: ['EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:3857']
       wms:
         md:
           title: Mapproxy_Test
           abstract: Mapproxy_Test
         srs: ['EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:3857']
         image_formats: ['image/png']
         max_output_pixels: [4000, 4000]
     layers:
       - name: Mapproxy_Test_RGB
         title: Mapproxy_Test_RGB
         sources: [rgb_cache]
     caches:
       rgb_cache:
         grids: [webmercator]
         sources: [rgb]
         format: image/png
         request_format: image/png
         disable_storage: false
         concurrent_tile_creators: 5
     sources:
       rgb:
         type: tile
         grid: webmercator
         url: https://storage.googleapis.com/mapproxy_example/terrebonne-parish-imagery-pyramid-tiles/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s
         transparent: true
         on_error:
           other:
             response: transparent
             cache: False
         coverage:
           srs: 'EPSG:3857'
           bbox: [-10221164.113,3320585.742,-10014524.117,3500502.768]
         http:
           ssl_no_cert_checks: true 
     grids:
       webmercator:
         base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
```

Comment: Would you be able to [edit] your question to include the Service URL that you are using when you try to add this to ArcMap, please?

Comment: Please see edit for WMTS GetCapabilities URL

Comment: Your WMTS GetCapabilities link seems to be broken so I am not able to try and reproduce this.  I was going to test it using ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Desktop.